# Secondary HDD not mounting

Tags: mount

My computer is:
System-76-Gazelle with Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

I am relatively new to Linux.
My system drive is a 250GB SSD, and a separate HDD (called 'ExtraDrive1') of 1TB.

I have been using ExtraDrive1 as a storage location.

A day ago I tried to mount ExtraDrive1 by double clicking and it did not open. I then tried to mount the drive using ‘disks’ utility and received this message:

```
     Error mounting /dev/sda1/media/ExtraDrive1: can't read superblock on /dev/sda1(udisks-error-quark,0)
```

I am thankful for any help which would enable me to mount the drive. I do not want to lose valuable data.

Comment: What filesystem is the drive formatted with?  Did the drive used to work?  Did you change or update anything recently?

Comment: Hi xiota, thank you for replying to my question. My filesystem is ext4(version 1.0). The drive worked fine since I bought the computer about 2.5 years ago. I update regularly - I just take all available updates, so it is difficult for me to be specific about a particular update. I did reinstall Ubuntu about 5 or 6 months ago.

Comment: What's the output of: `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` (typed in a terminal)?

Comment: Disk /dev/sda:   931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors.
Units:     sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes.
Sector size (logical/physical):   512 bytes / 4096 bytes.
I/O size (minimum/optimal):       4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type:     gpt
Disk identifier:      5BF1D1F-EBC6-498C-B7DB-8568E57EEBC7


Device:   /dev/sda1/
Start:    2048
End:      1953523711
Sectors:  1953521664
Size:     931.5G
Type:     Linux filesystem